# How to add blank rows when select query sql

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Example : 
when I type :

```
select number, city from user
```

The results in the get is 3 rows. How to `select` the row that I can be automatically filled in 8 rows? What if using a loop ?

Desired Output:

if 3 rows then there are 5 empty rows,

if 4 rows then there are 4 empty rows, etc ..

Comment: Why would you want to do that? Due to some presentation logic requirement? Database is meant to return actual data, not deal with presentation or other requirements. The middleware is used to handle that.

Comment: You can do this with `Union`, but you arguably shouldn't. What purpose is the blank rows supposed to be serving?

Comment: I smell a homework assignment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While I don't understand the cause of this task, anyway you can do it like :

```
DECLARE @t TABLE ( ID INT )
DECLARE @c INT  = 8

INSERT  INTO @t
VALUES  ( 1 ),
        ( 2 ),
        ( 3 );
WITH    cte
          AS ( SELECT   1 AS rn
               UNION ALL
               SELECT   rn + 1
               FROM     cte
               WHERE    rn <= @c
             )
    SELECT TOP ( @c )
            *
    FROM    ( SELECT    ID
              FROM      @t
              UNION ALL
              SELECT    NULL
              FROM      cte
            ) t
    ORDER BY ID DESC
```

Output:

```
ID
3
2
1
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
```