# Insert blank line in Detail section of Crystal Report

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I have an issue concerning inserting blank line in Detail Section of Crystal Report (using SAP Crystal Report with VS 2013)
For example, if there is only 01 record , it should be always 05 lines instead of 01 lines. The below is the form created in Excel

[image]

And here is the form created with Crystal Report:

[image]

I googled a lot but no solution is satisfied in my case.

Please help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: what happens if there are 6 lines? if the report is created through a stored procedure I would do something like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29487482/how-to-add-blank-rows-when-select-query-sql, otherwise if you create the report with a datatable create via c# I would add the missing lines via code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will suppose that you mean you need to always show 5 lines. So, if you have 2 items, there will be 3 blank lines. I will suppose you will never have 6 items (since you did not answer to Raphael question yet). I will suppose you can only work on the Crystal Reports design (otherwise you may try what Raphael suggested).

1. Let the details section showing the item fiels as you did.
2. Create blank new details section. Fill the lines of the grid. Put the number of the item using text boxes (2, 3, 4, 5). Note that you will have now the sections Detail A, Detail B, ..., Detail E.
3. Use the "Section Expert" to edit the "Supress" formulas of each black detail section. The formulas may be:

   Count ({ItemTableName.Id}) >= 2 OR recordNumber < Count ({ItemTableName.Id}) //Detail B suppress formula

   Count ({ItemTableName.Id}) >= 3 OR recordNumber < Count ({ItemTableName.Id}) //Detail C suppress formula

   Count ({ItemTableName.Id}) >= 4 OR recordNumber < Count ({ItemTableName.Id}) //Detail D suppress formula

   Count ({ItemTableName.Id}) >= 5 OR recordNumber < Count ({ItemTableName.Id}) //Detail E suppress formula

You may need to adapt this solution if you have groups or if the initial assumptions are not true.

[Here is a RPT file as an example](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bxb3pxCHYFruUUw0MG9Lak41X3M/view?usp=sharing&resourcekey=0-yQ_8LnsUiuWrCnLtmmERpA).

Answer (score 0):

first of all you have fix detail section 
then you want 5 blank rows if there are total 6 rows and 1 row have data then design detail section and under detail section -> Report section leave blank with needed space and put your footer details in page footer 
then check result ->it show blank rows as well after 6 rows it go next page for 7th row